# XSLT: save variable in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

My current stylesheet is below. It looks for all nodes of `<IMFile>` and deletes these children.  I would like to add another condition to it, but I am unsure how to do this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- Removes red boxes -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Strip IMFile elements -->
   <xsl:template match="IMFile[@src='@variable']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So below are two sections that I need to look at. Mainly I just need to know how to get and use a variable. I would like to look in this source section and save 1 id that references when the `src="Red_Box.png"`. And apply this variable to my code (replacing the @variable). This id reflects the `@src` attribute of the `<IMFile>` element.

```
<SourceBin id="3"  >
  <Source id="4" src="something.trec" lastMod="20161202T191501" rect="(0,0,1920,1080)">
    <SourceTrack range="(0,9463)" type="0" editRate="30/1" trackRect="(0,0,1920,1080)" sampleRate="0/1" bitDepth="0" numChannels="0" filename="something.trec.trec!Strack0.tsc2" metaData="something.trec;" />
  </Source>
  <Source id="5" src="screenshot_449.png" lastMod="20161202T191503" rect="(0,0,1912,1078)" >
   <SourceTrack range="(0,1)" type="1" editRate="10000000/1" trackRect="(0,0,1912,1078)" sampleRate="0/1" bitDepth="24" numChannels="0" filename="" metaData="" />
  </Source>
  <Source id="6" src="Red-Box.png" lastMod="20161202T191503" rect="(0,0,1600,1200)" >
    <SourceTrack range="(0,1)" type="1" editRate="10000000/1" trackRect="(0,0,1600,1200)" sampleRate="0/1" bitDepth="32" numChannels="0" filename="" metaData="" />
  </Source>
</SourceBin>
    <IMFile id="6907" start="754" duration="8" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="0/1" mediaDuration="1/1" trackNumber="0" src="5" trimStartSum="67/1" >
<IMFile id="6907" start="754" duration="8" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="0/1" mediaDuration="1/1" trackNumber="0" src="6" trimStartSum="67/1" >
<IMFile id="6907" start="754" duration="8" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="0/1" mediaDuration="1/1" trackNumber="0" src="6" trimStartSum="67/1" >
```

If I had the above 3 IMFile I would want it to see that 2 of them use the src="6" (which is the id of the source child that uses Red_Box.png). And result in both of them deleted:

```
<IMFile id="6907" start="754" duration="8" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="0/1" mediaDuration="1/1" trackNumber="0" src="5" trimStartSum="67/1" >
```

Comment: What would your desired output look like? And btw., where are the `Callout` elements in your XML that you like to filter out? A [mcve] would be helpful (for us to answer your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am guessing (!) correctly, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="source-by-id" match="Source" use="@id" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Strip IMFile elements -->
<xsl:template match="IMFile[key('source-by-id', @src)/@src='Red-Box.png']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will remove any `IMFile` element that is linked (via the [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)) to a `Source` element whose `src` attribute is `"Red-Box.png"`.

---

Demo (using a **well-formed** input): http://xsltransform.net/ejivdJc

Comment: You are amazing! This is perfect! I don't even see how it gets only the Red-Box.png id value, but it works (for the few tests I did)!

Comment: It works through a **key** - which is an extremely useful tool in the XSLT toolbox. Here, it allows you to "see" the `src` value  of the related `Source` from the context of `IMFile`.